# Convert lat/lon points to gridded panel dataset?

Tags: r, rasterization

Suppose I had a dataset that looked like `df`. Could someone show me how I would I summarize this panel dataset into a panel by km x km grids **in R**?

```
df <- expand.grid(decade = seq(1940, 2010, 10),
              country = c("Spain", "Italy"),
              stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df$lat    <- 36   + (3 * runif(16)) 
df$lon    <- -5.5 + (2 * runif(16))
df$events <- sample(1:50, 16, TRUE)
```

I want to aggregate this data, not only into grids, but keep the time dimension as part of the end product. What I'd like to create is a data frame that will tell me how many total events happened by grid in decade 1950.